# a necessary and sufficient condition for increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis

given that: $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

satisfies: $\forall \{h_n\}^\infty_{n=1}\rightarrow 0$, $n \rightarrow 0$, $h_n \neq 0$. we have $\varliminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x + h_n) - f(x)}{h_n} \geq0$.

How to prove that $f$ is an increasing function (i.e. $x \leq y$ implies that $f(x) \leq f(y)$)?

(the inverse proposition is simple)

Comment: My instinct: if there exists $x<y$ with $f(x)>f(y)$, repeatedly bisect the interval $[x,y]$, redefining (to be the midpoint) whichever of $x$ and $y$ is needed to keep $f(x) > f(y)$; after infinitely many bisections we ought to have a sequence that contradicts the lim-inf hypothesis.

Comment: Tip: use $\mathbb{R}$ to denote the real numbers. Code is ```\mathbb{R}```

Comment: @K.defaoite thanks, edited.

Comment: @Greg Martin you are right, I've got it. Thank you!